# longtable header continued overlaps with default page header

Tags: header-footer, longtable, page, overlap

I have a default page header for all pages of my document. And the longtable headers which continue to the new pages overlap the default page header. Is there a way to make the continued longtable to leave enough vertical space to avoid overlap with the default page header?

Thanks!
Reshmi

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Normally longtable heads and foots go inside the text area, w;hile headers and footers go outside the text area (see geometry or showframe packages).  So your code must be doing something very sketchy.

Answer (score 0):

something like that?

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{lipsum} % for dummy text, remove this line in your actual document

% Set up the default page header
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\lhead{Default Page Header}
\rhead{\thepage}

% Adjust the vertical space for longtable headers
\setlength{\LTpre}{10pt} % adjust the space before longtable headers
\setlength{\LTpost}{10pt} % adjust the space after longtable headers

\begin{document}

% Your document content goes here

\lipsum[1-3] % dummy text, replace this with your actual longtable

% Example of longtable usage
\begin{longtable}{ll}
\hline
\textbf{Column 1} & \textbf{Column 2} \\
\hline
\endhead
\hline
\endfoot
Data 1 & Data 2 \\
Data 3 & Data 4 \\
Data 1 & Data 2 \\
% ... more rows
\hline
\caption{Example Longtable}
\end{longtable}
% Continue with the rest of your document
\end{document}
```